# What is the name of the instrument that separates substances using an electromagnetic field, similar to spectrography

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, centrifugal-force, nuclear-engineering, elements

As far as I remember, the elements of the substance are passed across an electromagnetic field in such a way that they seperate as the electromagnetic field alters their trajectory. I also seem to remember centrifuges being involved.

Comment: Electrophoresis?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meam a [Mass Spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry).

In a Mass Spectrometer, ions are separated while flying though electric and magnetic fields

Among other things they were used (under the name [Calutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calutron)) to separate Uranium isotopes during the Manhattan Project. The scientists needed to separate the $^{235}U$ from the rest of the metal, as it was the main fission isotope.

Your suggestion of centrifuges may come from the fact that they are currently the main method used for $^{235}U$ separation. The Manhattan Project ended up using yet another technique, [Gaseous Diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaseous_diffusion)

Comment: And liquid diffusion...